# Should We put Connection in 1 method & PreparedStatement in a seperated method (Java)?

Tags: java

Here is my problem, I need to select data, but the data may be a lot so need to select the total results as well, so i need to call `PreparedStatement` twice for the same fields.  I don't want to repeatedly write the same code twice, so I want put `PreparedStatement` into a different method. See ex:

```
public Order getOrders(){
     Connection myCon = null;
     PreparedStatement preparedStmt=null;
     try{
        myCon =getUnusedConnection();
        String sql="select * from order where name=? ....... limit 0,3";
        preparedStmt=myCon.prepareStatement(sql);
        getOrderPreparedStatement(name,....);

        ResultSet results=preparedStmt.executeQuery();
        int rowCount=0;
        while(results.next()){
           ......
             rowCount++;
        }
        if(rowCount==3){
             String sql2="select count(*) from Order where name=?....";
             preparedStmt=myCon.prepareStatement(sql);
             getOrderPreparedStatement(name,....);
             ResultSet results2=preparedStmt.executeQuery();
             if(results2){
                int totalRow=....;
             }

         }

     }
     catch (SQLException ex) {
        while (ex != null) {
            System.out.println ("SQL Exception:  " +
                              ex.getMessage ());
            ex = ex.getNextException ();
        }
    }catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        System.out.println("***ERROR-->" + e.toString());   
    }
    finally {

        closeStatement(preparedStmt);
        releaseConnection(myCon); 
    }
    return null;
}
public void getOrderPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement preparedStmt, String name....)
{
       try{
           preparedStmt.setString(name);
        ... a lot of set field here....
       }
       catch (SQLException ex) {
            while (ex != null) {
                System.out.println ("SQL Exception:  " +
                              ex.getMessage ());
                ex = ex.getNextException ();
            } 
        }catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
            System.out.println("***ERROR-->" + e.toString());   
        }
        finally {
            closeStatement(preparedStmt);  // do i need to close Statement in finally here
        }
}
```

Is it a good practice to  put Connection in 1 method & PreparedStatement in a seperated method. If it is ok to do that then "do i need to `closeStatement` in `finally` in `getOrderPreparedStatement` method?"

Or can u suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is definitely a good idea to move the code for repeated tasks into a method, you need to be very careful when deciding how much code to reuse.

Specifically, in your example you should not attempt to close the statement in the `finally` clause, because the statement that you prepare would be unusable outside the `getOrderPreparedStatement`.

One thing that you could do differently is dropping the exception-handling code from the method. This would keep the logic inside the method cleaner, so your readers would have easier time understanding your intentions. This would also reduce code duplication, because currently the code inside the `catch (SQLException ex)` block is identical.

Comment: so i need to remove finally in getOrderPreparedStatement right? if i remove it then is there any serious problem? what if preparedStatement got err in getOrderPreparedStatement method?

Comment: us said "do differently is dropping the exception-handling code from the method" then how to put preparedStatement into another method but don't need ExceptionHandling Code??

Comment: @Tum Currently, your `getOrderPreparedStatement` method is not intended for use in methods that don't do `SQLException` handling, because it is too low-level: all it does is preparing a statement of a special kind for further use, assuming that the connection and closing is done outside `getOrderPreparedStatement`. That's why it should simply declare `SQLException` in its `throws` header, letting the caller handle exceptions. Moreover, it's a good idea to make the method `private`, perhaps even `static` (depending on what other parts of your class it uses).

Comment: so u mean, just need "private static void getOrderPreparedStatement(..) throws SQLException"? do i need "throws SQLException, Exception" or just "throws SQLException"?

Comment: @Tum I would keep it to just "`throws SQLException`", because `throws Exception` "shadows" all other exceptions, making the declaration too demanding on the caller, because they must catch everything now.